# Collection interface

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create an ArrayList Object to use the Collection interface. But my code has a problem. It says

`I use checked and unsafe operation, please use -Xlint: unchecked to restart compile`.

I want to know how to solve this problem.

Below is my java-code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class testCollection{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> collection1 = new ArrayList<>();
        collection1.add("New York");
        collection1.add("Atalnta");
        collection1.add("Dallas");
        collection1.add("Madison");

        System.out.println("A list of cities in collection1:");
        System.out.println(collection1);

        System.out.println("\nIs Dallas in collection1?"
            +collection1.contains("Dallas"));


        Collection<String> collection2 = new ArrayList<>();
        collection2.add("Seattle");
        collection2.add("Portland");
        collection2.add("Los Angeles");
        collection2.add("Atalnta");
        System.out.println("\nA list of cities in collection2:");
        System.out.println(collection2);

        ArrayList<String> c1 = (ArrayList<String>)(collection1.clone());
        c1.addAll(collection2);
        System.out.println("\nCities in collection1 or collection2?");
        System.out.println(c1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList#clone()` returns an `Object` and you're attempting to cast said `Object` to a generic type which is unsafe. If you want to keep using this approach then the only way to stop the warning is to suppress it, either via the command line or with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. A more appropriate fix, however, is to use the copy constructor typically present in `Collection` implementations as shown in [R Wri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58309254/6395627).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
ArrayList<String> c1 = (ArrayList<String>)(collection1.clone());
```

It is returning an Object that you are then Casting to an ArrayList.

The proper way to turn a Collection into an ArrayList is:

```
ArrayList<String> c1 = new ArrayList<String>(collection1);
```